PayPal WooCommer Plugin Update Issue
After updating the PayPal plugin in WooCommerce (WooCommerce PayPal Payments v2.7.1 by WooCommerce) for a client, the PayPal buttons in our store are now greyed out and cannot be utilized. It also appears that the checkbox for Vaulting is greyed out and we cannot access that function, which is needed.
Two things that we need to figure out ASAP:

Renewal Payments: is this issue going to affect renewal payments for their store.
New Payments: we need to get this sorted so that we can accept PayPal again ASAP from their checkout flow.

Looking at the error logs for the App in PayPal Developer, I see that there is a Business Error for multiple transaction attempts.
Here is a sample error response based on what it shows
Request:
{
   "description":"Checking if reference transactions are enabled",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"PAYPAL"
   },
   "plan":{
      "type":"MERCHANT_INITIATED_BILLING",
      "merchant_preferences":{
         "return_url":"https://example.com/return",
         "cancel_url":"https://example.com/cancel",
         "skip_shipping_address":true
      }
   }
}

Response:
{
   "name":"BUSINESS_ERROR",
   "debug_id":"[DEBUG ID]",
   "message":"Business error",
   "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#BUSINESS_ERROR",
   "details":[
      {
         "name":"UNAUTHORISED ACCESS",
         "message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions. Invalid Scopes"
      }
   ]
}

I've updated the WooCommerce PayPal plugin for my client and it is not working now, greyed out in checkout. It appears that there are insufficient permissions, even though the account has Vaulting permissions, etc.
